# Cannot read first line of a file

Tags: java, java-8

I want to read the content of /etc/passwd file and get some data:

```
public void getLinuxUsers()
    {
        try
        {
            // !!! firstl line of the file is not read
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/etc/passwd"));
            String str;
            str = in.readLine();
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] ar = str.split(":");
                String username = ar[0];
                String userID = ar[2];
                String groupID = ar[3];
                String userComment = ar[4];
                String homedir = ar[5];

                System.out.println("Usrname " + username + 
                        " user ID " + userID);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File Read Error");
        }
    }
```

I noticed two problems:

first line of the file is not read with root account information. I starts this way:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
```

And how I can modify the code to use Java 8 NIO? I want to check first the existing of the file and then to proceed with reading the content.

Comment: Close your reader in a finally block. Or use the try-with-resources statement. This code leaks file descriptors if exceptions happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the first `readLine()` is *outside* the loop where the string is being processed, you should delete this:

```
str = in.readLine();
```

… Because in the next line (the one with the `while`) you're reassigning the `str` variable, that's why the first line is lost: the loop's body starts processing from the second line. Finally, to use Java `nio`, do something like this:

```
if (new File("/etc/passwd").exists()) {
    Path path = Paths.get("/etc/passwd");
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
    for (String line : lines) {
        // loop body, same as yours
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1285928 what do you mean? simply delete the line _before_ the `while`.

Comment: @user1285928 ok, you got it

Answer (score 2):

with nio:

```java
Path filePath = Paths.get("/etc/passwd");
List<String> fileLines = Files.readAllLines(filePath);
```

Note that Files.readAllLines without 2nd parameter treats the file encoding as UTF-8, instead of system encoding (property "file.encoding")